# Django command throws TypeError: handle() got an unexpected keyword argument

Tags: django, python-3.5

I'm using Django 1.10.4 and Python 3.52. When I try to run a Django command via `python manage.py my_command` I get the following error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "path_to_envs/envs/env_name/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "path_to_envs/envs/env_name/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 359, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "path_to_envs/envs/env_name/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 294, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "path_to_envs/envs/env_name/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 345, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
TypeError: handle() got an unexpected keyword argument 'verbosity'
```

I can run a local django server and interact with the admin pages. The app that contains that command is in my `settings.py` file.

Below is the contents of the django command:

```
from django.core.management import BaseCommand
from my_module import MyClass


class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self):
        my_class = MyClass()
        my_class.my_method()
```

At the time of error, the `options` dictionary contains `{'verbosity': 1, 'no_color': False, 'settings': None, 'pythonpath': None, 'traceback': False}`. Depending on the random ordering of the dictionary `no_color`, `traceback`, and the others will throw the same `TypeError`. After a day of googling I still can't figure out what the issue is. Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Shouldn't you show the code of my_command?

Comment: @DanielRoseman My apologies. The command is so simple I didn't bother adding it. It's in the question now.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

After lots of googling and pulling my hair out, the issue was an incorrect number of arguments to `handle()`.

This:

```
    def handle(self):
```

Should be:

```
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
```

Comment: Hah!  Still relevant in Django 2.0 and Python 3.6! I ran into this while adapting a package that SAID it was updated to the current versions syntax - apparently they missed a couple of things!

Comment: Omg thanks! Worked for Django 3 and Python 3.6

Answer (score -3):

If your command needs no arguments, try a [subclass of BaseCommand](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-management-commands/#basecommand-subclasses)

```
NoArgsCommand.handle_noargs(**options)
```