# Passing in date string to Django management argument

Tags: python, django, django-management-command

I have a Django management command, which I pass like this:

`python manage.py tenant_command generate_weekly_invoice --start_date 2020-11-30 00:00:00 --end_date 2020-12-06 23:59:00 --schema=schema_name`

This doesn't work and I get an error saying that:

> argument 1 must be str, not None

I suspect this is to do with the way the actual string of the date `2020-11-30 00:00:00` is being formatted. My management command code is below

***generate_weekly_invoice.py***

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Generates weekly invoice'

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('--start_date', nargs='+')
        parser.add_argument('--end_date', nargs='+')
    
    def handle(self, *args, **options):

        start_str = options.get('--start_date')
        end_str = options.get('--end_date')

        start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        end_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(end_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

        ___Logic goes here___
```

Any help is appreciated

*** Edit:

I should have explained, that I have passed the string in quotation marks but it still returns the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because a space is seen as a parameter *separator*. You can wrap the parameters over single/double quotes, so `--start_date '2020-11-30 00:00:00'` instead of <s>`--start_date 2020-12-06 23:59:00`</s>:

```
python manage.py tenant_command generate_weekly_invoice --start_date '2020-11-30 00:00:00' --end_date '2020-12-06 23:59:00' --schema=schema_name
#                                      pass the datetimes as a single parameter ↑                                ↑
```

This is because a space is seen as a parameter *separator*. You can wrap the parameters over single/double quotes, so `--start_date '2020-11-30 00:00:00'` instead of <s>`--start_date 2020-12-06 23:59:00`</s>:

```
python manage.py tenant_command generate_weekly_invoice --start_date '2020-11-30 00:00:00' --end_date '2020-12-06 23:59:00' --schema=schema_name
#                                      pass the datetimes as a single parameter ↑                                ↑
```

additionally, your misunderstood how parameters are handled. This is *without* the double hyphens. You can thus use `options.get('start_date')`, but it is better to simply use the names of the parameters, and drop the `nargs='+'`, since that means one can pass *multiple* `--start_date`s, etc:

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Generates weekly invoice'

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('--start_date')  # ← no nargs='+'
        parser.add_argument('--end_date')    # ← no nargs='+'
    
    def handle(self, start_date, end_date, **kwargs):
        start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        end_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(end_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

If you want to parse `--start_date` multiple times, then you can use `nargs='+'`, but then `start_date` and `end_date` will be *lists* of strings, not a single string, so then you need to perform a mapping.

Comment: This doesn't work, I tried this previously

Comment: Thank you, I am a little bit closer but now get this error: "handle() got an unexpected keyword argument 'verbosity'

Comment: @Rutnet: sorry, made a typo, at the end, `verbosity` and `traceback` should be added.

Comment: Now I get this error, handle() got an unexpected keyword argument 'settings'. Looking at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41401202/django-command-throws-typeerror-handle-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument it says too many arguments passed